# Кто сейчас онлайн? Без использования БД

Tags: php

Собственно сам вопрос: как можно узнать, кто сейчас на сайте в данный момент и вывести его имя? Обязательно без использования БД. Пока вожусь с сессиями, но ничего не выходит.

Comment: Если не считать вариант занесения в файлик логина после авторизации и удаления после выхода / не нахождения на сайте больше 10 минут как БД то только так.

Comment: а куки не поможет ??

Comment: Тоже была такая идея с файлом, но если например пользователь не нажал кнопку выхода, а просто закрыл браузер, то так и будет висеть в файле получается.

Comment: В БД будет то же самое.

Comment: @Vfvtnjd Куки в чистом виде не поможет, поскольку нет обратной связи.

Comment: Лол. А следить за временем последней активности и при переходе на каждую новую страницу обновлять это самое место нельзя? Больше 10 минут нет активности — оффлайн.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Общее для всех сессий сайта хранилище, чаще всего — БД и файловая система. БД отметаем, остаются файлы. Организовать можно по-разному.

**В один файл** писать через таб строки:

```
userid    timestamp    имя
```

При каждом запросе страницы, читать этот файл целиком, удалять те строки, где timestamp старше N, обновлять его для текущего юзера.

Можно создавать в отдельной папке **по файлу под каждого юзера**, называть их по его id, или через точку id и имя: "`15165.Вася Пупкин`". При запросе обновлять содержание файла. И полагаться на [дату модификации файла](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php), для определения времени, когда чел загружал страницу последний раз. Файлы старше N стирать.

Comment: Благодарю, попробую :)